# how can we calculate Mathieu wavelet filter coefficients from its design equation? a detailed explanation will be highly appreciated

Tags: filters, wavelet

[Elliptic-Cylindrical Wavelets: The Mathieu Wavelets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07255.pdf)

Comment: Maybe these toolbox functions (Matlab code) helps ... https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22081-mathieu-functions-toolbox-v-1-0